# jQuery Autocomplete to Show `No Results` only when `Enter` is pressed

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
  $('#term').catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response){
      $.post('/search/super_search', {'term': $('#term').val()}, function(data){
        if (data.length > 0) {
          response(data);
        } else  {
          response([{label: 'No Results', category:"", href:""}, {label: 'Please try your search again.', category: "", href: ""}])
        }
      });
    }
}
```

I currently have the code above. Which only results in `No results` when no results are sent back. However what I need to do is to only return `No results` when there are no resuls AND when the user pressed enter.

Edit: I am looking into accessing the event from the source method. Is there a way for me to access that in the source method?

Comment: Is it catcomplete or autocomplete?

Comment: Is the concern that the user hasn't "submitted" their search yet, but they are getting "no results" when they may still have more input? Because technically "no results" isn't wrong and as long as it continues to re-search on each keypress, the user shouldn't be too discouraged.  Maybe a better solution would be to have 2 output messages based on different minimum input. So if it's under, say, 6, they get "Nothing yet..." but 6 or higher gets "no results". I say this not to discourage your intention, but to suggest alternatives that cause less issues with different keyboards, inputs, etc.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I need to know if he pressed the return key. If he did and there are no results, only then would I show him the `No Results` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few parts to your answer:

1. I don't see any way to do this via the `source` option, since `source` is not tied to any event.
2. The `search` option is, however, is tied to the `autocompletesearch` event, and it's callback function can be passed in the `event` and `ui` objects for inspection.  But there is a catch: from my testing and searching, it ignores most of the "meta" keypress events (such as `shift`,`enter`,`return`).

This leaves you with two options:

1. Have your remote script test to see if the last character in the `term` string is a newline character. This may or may not work, depending on if the browser captures the `13` keypress and passes it along.
2. Have an external event handler listen for the `keypress` in a separate function and set a flag that gives the go-ahead for the autocomplete's `search` option. Something like:

   ```
   var getResults = false;

   $("#term").keypress(function(event) {
       getResults = (event.which == 13);
   });

     $('#term').catcomplete({
       delay: 0,
       minLength: 2,
       search: function(event, ui) {
             return getResults;
       },
       source: function(request, response){
         $.post('/search/super_search', {'term': $('#term').val()}, function(data){
           if (data.length > 0) {
             response(data);
           } else  {
             response([{label: 'No Results', category:"", href:""}, {label: 'Please try your search again.', category: "", href: ""}])
           }
         });
       }
   ```

Now, I'm having trouble with this method, personally. But I think it has more to do with my testing environment than the actual logic. There may be a way to simplify this further,  but the basic idea is that the `search` option's callback returns true or false and the autocomplete fires based on this, combined with the limitation that `enter` does not trigger as an event, so it must be captured elsewhere.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I have done that but I manually outputted the `div` to the position where the autocomplete shows

Answer (score 0):

you could store the string 'no results' or something like that in a variable in your callback function he there are no results, and check that string when the user presses enter, and send nothing back instead of 'no result'

Comment: I know when I have no results. The problem is when the user presses enter. From the source, I could know if there are results but I can't determine if the user pressed enter from there. I need to know if both the user pressed `Enter` and when there are not results.

Comment: @ThorpeObazee - By "pressed Enter" you mean the user is "done typing" right?